# i am having css hover issue in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

here is a page URL http://psd2htmlexpert.com/jem-08/ please go to 09 and you will see 3 red circles when you tap it will show another circle but its never disappear exactly when i tap outside i tried much thing can anyone help me.

here is html

```
<figure class="sun_wide">
<div class="green_question">Did You know That</div>
<div class="sgls">Enough sunlight falls on the roof of the average suburban home to supply   3 times as much energy as that home consumes? </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Have you tried `focus` instead of `hover`?

Comment: I don't find such a problem you mentioned,when I tap on it nothing is happening, but when I hover a new circle come and it disappears as the mouse moves out

Comment: did you check on ipad?

Comment: @Morpheus can you please guide me how i can fix this. :(

Comment: `.sun_wide:focus .sgls`

Comment: @Morpheus no its not working with focus :(

Comment: @rich-bradshaw can you please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Safari Dev Library](http://bit.ly/Zgip9P):

> Mouse events are delivered in the same order you'd expect in other web browsers… If the user taps a non-clickable element, no events are generated.

So focus will only be changed by clicking another 'clickable' element. Tapping the background `div` as seen in your case will do nothing.

I wrote a more in-depth explanation on my site: http://maketea.co.uk/2013/03/12/why-does-hover-work-on-my-ipad.html